# swap two panels in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have 2 panels & i want to swap those 2 panels. how can i do that in web application..?

Comment: What do you mean you want to swap them?

Comment: i have 2 pannels with 2 buttons left & right. when i click on right button pannel should go to right & the pannel which was at right side should come on keft side

Answer (score 0):

You could just swap their locations.  Something like this would probably work.

```
Point temp = Panel1.location;
Panel1.Location=Panel2.Location;
Panel2.Location=temp;
```

This way, you are merely swapping the location of the panels (and their contents).